# why getting the message "/Users/<My User Name>/.zshrc:1: command not found: plug" even after removing zplug?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I get this message although I have removed `zplug` from the system.

I have removed it from `brew` and removed all.zshrc related configurations with `source .zshrc`. I even get that message after each sourcing .zshrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Try to exit and relogin.

(2) Here, "/Users//.zshrc:1: command not found: plug" means that in line 1 , `/Users/<My User Name>/.zshrc` still has references to `plug` command.
Open `/Users/<My User Name>/.zshrc` with text editor and delete that line and other lines having `plug` command, and save it. It should not occur now.

Comment: I have done that, But I forget about this line: `plug version     # Fig pre block. Keep at the top of this file.` today I catch it and delete it. thanks.